# my php echo statement for an <a href="#"> is making the url visible

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am going by this tutorial (https://redvinestudio.com/how-to-build-isotope-portfolio-in-your-wordpress-theme/), and when I am working on the part where the portfolio items are displayed as links, the url that the link leads to is being displayed above the item. Below is the prescribed code:

```
echo '<div class="all portfolio-item '. $tax .'">';
echo '<a href="'. the_permalink() .'" title="'. the_title_attribute() .'">';
echo '<div class="thumbnail">'. the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') .'</div>';
echo '<h2>'. the_title() .'</h2>';
echo '</a>';
/*echo '<div>'. the_excerpt() .'</div>';*/
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `the_permalink()` within an `echo`, because it `echo`es data itself. Instead, you need to use [get_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/). You also need to modify `the_title_attribute()` to avoid a duplicated `echo` there:

```
echo '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="'. the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) .'">';
```

EDIT: You need to comb through your code to remove all instances of code that is echoing content within an `echo`. This includes `the_title()`, `the_post_thumbnail()`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm! Also after asking the question I noticed the problem with the the_title() section. changing it to get_the_title() did the job! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

the_permalink() will always echo the URL of the object, which means you're telling it to echo twice. Change it to get_permalink() and it should work.